# Limit characters on multiple items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple divs generated by PHP and I am attempting to limit characters on each of the 'div p' tags I have that are under this class.

Each of the paragraphs have a different quote, but need to be limited to a word count of 140. However I'm sure I've overlooked some part to make it select each 'div p' one by one and adjust with the character limit.

```
var txtlimit = $('.release p').text();
txtlimit = txtlimit.substring(0, 141);
$('.release p').html(txtlimit);
console.log(txtlimit);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G5BLx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this from your php script. but if you want to do thist at client side for somewhat reason you can do this as..

```
$('.release p').each(function(){
  var txtlimit = $trim($(this).text());
  if (txtlimit.length > 140) {
     txtlimit = txtlimit.substring(0, 140);
     $(this).html(txtlimit);
  }

});
```

## sorry i have missed your lines **for word count upto 140**

```
 $('.release p').each(function(){
   var aParagraphTxt = $trim($(this).text()).split(" ");
   var wordCount     = aParagraphTxt.length;

   if (wordCount > 140) {
      $(this).html(aParagraphTxt.slice(0,139).join(" "));
   }
 });
```

Comment: thank you, i don't know much PHP but i know a little javascript. So i was editing this from the client side, as bad of a coding practice it is.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to do this?

```
$('.release p').each(function() {
    var txtlimit = $(this).text();
    txtlimit = txtlimit.substring(0, 141);
    $(this).html(txtlimit);
    console.log(txtlimit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're selecting the `p` tags you would set them all with the same text as the first, you need to pass through `each` of them to set their texts accordingly

```
$.each($('.release p'),function(index, value){
   var txtlimit = $(this).text().split(" ");      //splits into array of words
   $(this).html(txtlimit.slice(0,139).join(" ")); //get words from 0 to 139
});
```

**FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/y53r7/3/